# Excel 2016 COUNTIFS Change

Tags: excel

In Excel 2013 you were able to select multiple "criteria" in a single "criteria range" if you put it in { }.

Code Example: =COUNTIFS(A1:A10,{"A","B","C"})

This code would count all the cells with a value of A, B, or C.

In Excel 2016, it seems that it will only count the first item in the criteria range when using the code above. It also appears that you still can't use the OR function to solve this problem.

Does anyone have a solution for how to use multiple "criteria" in a single "criteria range" without exploding it into 3 separate COUNTIF functions SUM'd together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put SUM() around the formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:A10,{"A","B","C"}))
```